# Showing a Simple Multivariable Function is Differentiable

Tags: limits, multivariable-calculus, derivatives

So the other day I received this question and I got stuck on what seems like a simple step. The idea of what was to be done was quite straight forward, but to reach the end goal I had to prove some term approaches zero.
I tried many things, however, I just can't manage to find the correct way. I shall present the question and show where I got stuck.

The question:

> Let $f:\mathbb{R}^k \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be continuously differentiable in $a$ and satisfy $f(a) = 0$.
> Define $g: x \rightarrow f(x)^2$.
>
> Prove $g$ is differentiable **twice** in $a$ and that $Hg_a = 2\nabla f^T \nabla f$.

Well, as the question is quite simple, I think my way of solving it is equally simple.
Given $f$ is continuously differentiable in $a$ there exists a neighbourhood of $a$ such that $f$ is differentiable.
As we know, the function $\varphi: x \rightarrow x^2$ is differentiable in all of $\mathbb{R}$ and thus by the *chain rule* the gradient of $g$ is given by:

\begin{equation*}
    \nabla g(x) = \varphi'(f(x)) \nabla f(x) = 2 f(x) \nabla f(x)
\end{equation*}

By the definition of the Hessian (if it exists): $Hg_a = J(\nabla g)_a$.
Let us check if $\nabla g$ is differentiable in $a$ by using the limit definition of differentiability, assuming $J(\nabla g)_a = 2\nabla f^T(a) \nabla f(a)$.
\begin{align*}
    & \frac{2 f(a + h) \nabla f(a + h) - 2 f(a) \nabla f(a) - h \big( 2 \nabla f(a)^T \nabla f(a)\big)^T}{|h|}\\
    = & \frac{2 f(a + h) \nabla f(a + h) - 0 - 2 h \nabla f(a)^T \nabla f(a)}{|h|} \xrightarrow[h \rightarrow 0^{[k]} ]{?} 0^{[k]}
\end{align*}
This is kind of where I got stuck. I tried many directions like using the fact that $f$ is differentiable in $a$ and that it is continuously differentiable in $a$, but unfortunately I wasn't able to use these limits to my advantage here. I thought that perhaps using these facts about $f$, will help factor out some gradients from the numerator and then we're basically done,
but I really didn't see a way to make it work.
Tried all sorts of inequalities like the *triangle inequality* and *Cauchy-Schwartz* nothing seems to bring me closer to show this limit approaches $0$.

Thank you so much for reading my question, I would be extremely grateful for any hints or comments.
Have a good morning, evening, or night!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the formula $Dg_x=2f(x)\cdot Df_x$, we see that if everything was nice and differentiable, we would apply the product rule as $D^2g_x=2 f(x)D^2f_x + 2Df_x\otimes Df_x$. So, in our attempt to prove the twice differentiability of $g$, we should mimic the proof of the product rule. If you recall the proof, at one stage we have to carefully add and subtract a term. In your case, the crucial part is that $f(a)=0$.

By the way, I think you have a typo in your work, the $h$ (assuming you think of it as a column vector, which is usually how things go) should always appear on the right, not the left. Now observe that (I divide by 2 for convenience)
\begin{align}
\frac{Dg_{a+h}-Dg_a - 2Df_a(h)\cdot Df_a}{2} &= f(a+h)Df_{a+h}-Df_a(h)\cdot Df_a\\
&=\bigg[f(a+h)-f(a)-Df_a(h)\bigg]\cdot Df_{a+h} + Df_{a}(h)\cdot \bigg[Df_{a+h}-Df_a\bigg]
\end{align}
Now, if you put absolute values everywhere, and divide by  $\lVert h\rVert$, use the triangle inequality to split up into two terms, you should be able to justify why each of them goes to $0$ (the reasoning is different for each term).

Comment: First of all thank you so much for the elaborate answer. It is a little more complicated than I thought, I will never get use to these subtract-add tricks :(
But anyway regarding the typo, I don't know, for me the default is always a row vector, and this is how all my text book notates linear transformations (unless I misunderstood). @peek-a-boo

Comment: As for the terms, I believe the left one simply boils down to the fact that $f$ is differentiable in $a$ (we literally get the limit definition after dividing by $||h||$) and $x \rightarrow Df_x$ is defined and continuous (near $a$) and therefore bounded.
As for the right we get $\frac{h}{||h||} \cdot \nabla f(a)$ times something that approaches $0^{[k]}$ as we know $f$ is continuously differentiable in $a$. Pretty sure that is the reasoning for both. @peek-a-boo

Comment: @GamowDrop ok if you interpret $h$ as a row vector then fine. And yup you've got the right reasons for why both terms vanish. Regarding the add and subtract: when I solved the problem, I also didn't know *what* exactly to add and subtract; I just knew I had to add and subtract *something* (because it seemed so similar to product rule). To figure out what, I essentially forced by RHS to look like the numerator of the difference quotient, and then just compensated the extra terms accordingly.